# K-Means Variable Selection

Tags: r, k-means

I have a simple data set, 1200 Rows and 20 variables, 1 is a categorical variable with 8 unique values. 1 variable is a unique reference number. I'm looking into using Kmeans clustering to find the most effective/efficient number of clusters. Ideally these clusters should also match the 8 unique categories. I'm trying to figure out which variables to use and ignore, I don't have context for these variables just that they are measurements. Is there a logic or a principle that I can apply to these variables to include or exclude them scientifically?

Comment: Definitely exclude the reference number!

Comment: Kmeans will only attempt to minimize the within-group sum of squares, which may or may not have anything to do with the 8 categorical values.  Something like multinomial logistic regression might be more appropriate, as that will attempt to predict the likelihood that an observation fits into one of the 8 categories.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use k-means on data where you don't understand the importance(s) of the variables. Because k-means is very sensitive to scaling, and by choosing inappropriate scaling - or including inappropriate variables - the k-means result can suffer substantially.
So you should rather rely on other approaches of feature selection.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree I would not use this method with this data set. Truth is that its a course work question and I have to use K means. I suppose I need to do as much analysis as I can with those variables. Again thanks for the response.